# ¿Como evitar dentro un loop la misma entrada en la que me encuentro?

Tags: php, wordpress

no sabia como elaborar bien la pregunta pero espero que me entiendan porque es algo que surgió y necesito la ayuda de los mas experimentados en wordpress.

Cuando estoy dentro de una entrada 01 y debajo de toda la entrada hago un loop para mostrar mas entradas relacionadas deseo evitar que me aparezca la misma entrada 01 sobre la que que ya estoy leyendo. me gustaría saber como evitar eso.

les adjunto una imagen referencial.

[image: Imagen de lo que deseo evitar]

Comment: ¿Cuál es el código del loop de entradas relacionadas?

Comment: osea me encuentro leyendo la entrada 01 y al momento de hacer un loop de mas entradas en la parte inferior se repite la nuevamente la entrada 01 dentro del loop, como hago para evitar que esa miniatura de la misma entrada aparezca.

Answer (score 0):

Al escribir los demas post, excluye el actual de la siguiente manera:

```
$post = get_post();
$id_actual=$post->ID;
// Start the loop.
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

    if ( $id_actual != the_ID() ) {

    ...

    }

    // End of the loop.
endwhile;
```